# Looking for short science fiction story about a television program with people being "tortured" on stage..?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a short story I read once in the 10th grade.. I apologize if this is vague.. I don't remember much from it however would really like to read it again. Also I'm sorry if the title sounds weird, it wasn't a nasty story, I think it may have been loosely based on 1984 (we had just finished reading that book when we were assigned this)

It involves a television program or some sort of game show where the "contestants" have to wear these balls and chains attached to them to bog them down while they danced in front of a camera. It was very descriptive and wacky-- I think the people may have been described as looking like clowns.

Once again sorry if this is vague but it's killing me to find out! I'm considering just e-mailing my old English teacher and asking him if he knows!

Comment: Oh my god, yes! It is! I recognized it the minute I read the first line! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "[Harrison Bergeron](https://archive.org/stream/HarrisonBergeron/Harrison%20Bergeron_djvu.txt)" by Kurt Vonnegut, and is probably one of the most commonly assigned short stories in U.S. schools. In it, total equality has been mandated by Constitutional amendments, which is enacted through mechanisms of dubious validity—for example, weighing dancers down with chains.